# Downloading image creates grey artifacts in new file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Im trying to save an image from a url to a Django model.

When I try this code, I get grey pixels in the bottom of the image, like it is saved before reading the whole image.

Anyone see what could be wrong with this code, or know a better way to do this?

```
def save_image(img_url, img_pk):
    file_name = img_url.split('/')[-1]

    external_image = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)


    if external_image.status_code == 200:

        # Create a temporary file
        lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

        # Read the streamed image in sections
        for block in external_image.iter_content(1024 * 8):

            # If no more file then stop
            if not block:
                break

            # Write image block to temporary file
            lf.write(block)

            image_obj = Image.objects.get(pk=img_pk)
            image_obj.image.save(file_name, files.File(lf))
            image_obj.save()



            return image_obj
```

Comment: You are looping over the blocks of image content - and then writing the file and exiting the loop after the first block, no matter how much or how little of the image that was.  Those last four lines should be outside the loop.

Comment: You are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save_image(img_url, img_pk):
    file_name = img_url.split('/')[-1]

    external_image = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)


    if external_image.status_code == 200:

        # Create a temporary file
        lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

        # Read the streamed image in sections
        for block in external_image.iter_content(1024 * 8):

            # If no more file then stop
            if not block:
                break

            # Write image block to temporary file
            lf.write(block)

         #Save the image outside the foorloop
         image_obj = Image.objects.get(pk=img_pk)
         image_obj.image.save(file_name, files.File(lf))
         image_obj.save()



    return "Done"
```